# How to optimise slow mysql query

Tags: mysql

Below is my query which take 10 seconds almost to excute data i am new in this i dont know how to optimize this query

```
SELECT 
        dataa.,
        fn_ranks('user_ranks',dataa.pool_id, dataa.user_id, dataa.pp_id) AS userranks,
        ( if( fn_ranks('user_ranks', dataa.pool_id, dataa.user_id, dataa.pp_id) 
                BETWEEN fn_firstrank( 'firstrank', dataa.pool_id, dataa.user_id, dataa.pp_id) 
                    AND fn_lastrank( 'lastrank', dataa.pool_id, dataa.user_id, dataa.pp_id), 'win', 'lose')) AS poolstatus,
            if(( usedamount + fn_allrank( 'getalluserrank', dataa.pool_id, dataa.user_id, dataa.pp_id, 
                    '', '')) > usedamount, 'positive', 'negative') AS cuurentinvestkeyvalue 
    FROM 
        ( SELECT 
                val.,
                ( fn_allrank( 'getalluserrank', val.pool_id, val.user_id, val.pp_id, '', '' )
                    + (p_virtual_currency)) AS currentinvestamount,
                ( ( ( fn_allrank( 'getalluserrank', val.pool_id,val.user_id, val.pp_id, '', '' ) 
                    + ( p_virtual_currency)) - usedamount)
                    / ( usedamount )) 100 AS percentchange 
            FROM 
                ( SELECT 
                        myparam.,
                        SUM(myparam.investamount) AS usedamount 
                    FROM 
                        (SELECT 
                                s.pool_id,
                                s.pp_id,
                                us.user_id,
                                p.p_pool_name,
                                inves_amount AS investamount,
                                p.p_virtual_currency,
                                ( SELECT ( count(pm_torank) / (p.p_max_user)) 100 
                                    FROM 
                                        tbl_poolprizemoney AS pm 
                                            INNER JOIN tbl_pool AS p 
                                                ON pm.pm_poolid = p.p_id 
                                    WHERE 
                                        pm.pm_poolid = s.pool_id ) AS prizepercen,
                                MAX(pm_price) AS firstprice,
                                ( SELECT 
                                        SUM( pm_price(pm_torank - pm_fromrank + 1)) 
                                    FROM 
                                        tbl_poolprizemoney 
                                    WHERE 
                                        tbl_poolprizemoney. pm_poolid = us.pool_id) AS totalprice,
                                p.p_max_user,
                                p.p_entry_fee,
                                pp.pp_start_time,
                                pp.pp_end_time 
                            from 
                                tbl_user_stock AS us
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_stockpricemaster AS s 
                                        ON us.stock_id = s.stock_id
                                        AND us.pool_id = s.pool_id 
                                        AND us.publish_id = s.pp_id
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_pool AS p 
                                        ON us.pool_id = p.p_id
                                    INNER JOIN tbl_poolpublish AS pp 
                                        ON us.publish_id = pp.pp_id 
                                        AND us.pool_id = pp.pp_poolidINNER 
                                    JOIN tbl_poolprizemoney AS pm 
                                        ON us.pool_id = pm.pm_poolid 
                            WHERE 
                                    NOW() BETWEEN pp.pp_start_time AND pp.pp_end_time 
                                AND p.p_status = 'Active' 
                                AND us.user_id = 186 
                                AND p.p_min_user <= ( SELECT 
                                                            COUNT(fs_userid) 
                                                        FROM 
                                                            tbl_fivestock AS fss 
                                                        WHERE 
                                                                fss.fs_poolid = pp.pp_poolid 
                                                            AND fss.fs_publishid = pp.pp_id ) 
                                AND us.user_id = ( if( (( SELECT 
                                                                count(stock_id) 
                                                            FROM 
                                                                tbl_user_stock AS usu 
                                                            WHERE 
                                                                    usu.user_id = us.user_id 
                                                                AND usu.pool_id = s.pool_id 
                                                                AND usu.publish_id = s.pp_id ) = 5), us.user_id, 0)) 
                                                AND us.user_id = ( if( (( SELECT 
                                                                                sum(usus.inves_amount) 
                                                                            FROM 
                                                                                tbl_user_stock AS usus 
                                                                            WHERE 
                                                                                    usus.user_id = us.user_id 
                                                                                AND usus.pool_id = s.pool_id 
                                                                                AND usus.publish_id = s.pp_id )
                                                                        >= ( SELECT 
                                                                                    p_min_spent_amnt 
                                                                                FROM 
                                                                                    tbl_pool AS pl 
                                                                                WHERE 
                                                                                    pl.p_id=s.pool_id )), us.user_id, 0)) 
                            GROUP BY 
                                s.pool_id,
                                s.pp_id ) AS myparam ) AS val ) AS dataa
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck? Does the execution plan tell you something interesting?

Comment: First, having a somewhat readable SQL query would help.  Modified only to get that far.  Second, please EDIT your post and provide additional info.   You have provided NO context as to what you are trying to get, let alone, the query as-was would not run as you had things like "select alias., " with nothing like alias.*, or alias.SomeColumn and would fail.  What is purpose of query,  First rank, second, prize money.  Betting system and payout?  No details of the function?  Please describe in simple English what you are TRYING to get and why some of the otherwise bloat in this query.

Comment: You have load of nested SQLs there. Have you tried doing an explain on this query? You may be missing indexes on the tables. As a thumb rule, add indexes on the fields used in "where" and "join" which can speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

From the APPEARANCE the hierachy of your gambling pool is something like

```
A PoolPublished is within a given time period X and Y
  within Each PUBLISHING are multiple individual pools and may or not be active
    within each pool id there is a prize money result
```

Within your PrizeMoney, you have what APPEARS to be a function call pm_price via

```
SUM( pm_price(pm_torank - pm_fromrank + 1)) for the TotalPrice
```

but it also appears to be a column where determining the

```
MAX( pm_price )
```

Finally, all your calls to fun_allrank() vs fn_ranks() and dealing with what you had as "usedamount", that MAY need some adjustment.  However, with the complete LACK of table structures, and feedback of what you were trying to do, I think that MOST of what I have here WILL simplify the process and improve performance for you.

You will notice that I am pre-aggregating from the published pool activity FIRST to get: published date/time info, pool name, limits, fees, min/max pool sizes, etc., but ONLY for those within the current time period going on.  No sense querying what could be years of data.  Only from that does it also query for prize money and per-user stock/investment information.  Since the groupings are all grouped by respective publish id, pool id and ultimately per user within a given pool, the front-most numbers SHOULD be very close to what you are expecting (before all the rank callings).  If something is amiss, you will need to provide more info by editing you EXISTING post with data as needed for clarification.

```
select
        AP.publishid,
        AP.poolid,
        AP.PoolName,
        AP.MinimumPoolSize,
        AP.MaximumPoolSize,
        AP.PoolCount,
        AP.PoolCurrency,
        AP.PoolEntryFee,
        AP.PoolMinimumSpendAmount,
        AP.PublishPoolStartTime,
        AP.PublishPoolEndTime,
        Prize.FirstPrice,
        Prize.PriceCount,
        Prize.PriceCount / AP.MaximumPoolSize * 100.0 as PricePercent,
        Prize.SumTotalPrice,
        UserStock.User_ID,
        UserStock.StockCount,
        UserStock.InvestAmount,
        -- Now get ranks of a given user against all
        fn_allrank( 'getalluserrank', AP.poolid, UserStock.user_id, AP.Publishid, '', '' ) + AP.PoolCurrency  CurrentInvestAmount,
        ( fn_allrank( 'getalluserrank', AP.poolid, UserStock.user_id, AP.Publishid, '', '' )
                + AP.PoolCurrency - UserStock.InvestAmount) / UserStock.InvestAmount * 100.0 PercentChange,
        -- and finally to individual user ranks?
        fn_ranks( 'user_ranks', AP.poolid, UserStock.user_id, AP.Publishid ) UserRanks,
        if( fn_ranks('user_ranks', AP.poolid, UserStock.user_id, AP.Publishid ) 
                BETWEEN fn_firstrank( 'firstrank', AP.poolid, UserStock.user_id, AP.Publishid) 
                    AND fn_lastrank( 'lastrank', AP.poolid, UserStock.user_id, AP.Publishid)
            , 'win', 'lose') PoolStatus,
        if( UserStock.InvestAmount 
                + fn_allrank( 'getalluserrank', AP.poolid, UserStock.user_id, AP.Publishid, '', '') 
                > UserStock.InvestAmount, 'positive', 'negative') CuurentInvestKeyValue 
    from
        -- start by getting all ACTIVE Published pools within the time period in question
        -- get (via max() other parts from publish and pool while we are here once up-front).
        ( select
                pp.pp_id publishid,
                pp.pp_poolid poolid,
                max( p.p_pool_name ) PoolName,
                max( p.p_min_user ) MinimumPoolSize,
                max( p.p_max_user ) MaximumPoolSize,
                count(*) PoolCount,
                max( p.p_virtual_currency ) PoolCurrency,
                max( p.p_entry_fee ) PoolEntryFee,
                max( p.p_min_spent_amnt ) PoolMinimumSpendAmount,
                max( pp.pp_start_time ) PublishPoolStartTime,
                max( pp.pp_end_time ) PublishPoolEndTime
            from
                tbl_poolpublish AS pp
                    JOIN tbl_pool AS p 
                        ON pp.pp_poolid = p.p_id
                        AND p.p_status = 'Active'
                    JOIN tbl_fivestock fs
                        ON pp.pp_id = fs.fs_publishid
            where
                NOW() BETWEEN pp.pp_start_time AND pp.pp_end_time 
            group by
                pp.pp_id,
                pp.pp_poolid ) AP

            -- pre-aggregate prize money info
            -- using same WHERE condition to only get those published pools within same time period
            JOIN
            ( select
                    pp.pp_id publishid,
                    pp.pp_poolid poolid,
                    count(*) as PriceCount,
                    -- see comment about PM_PRICE as column vs parameterized function in two below?
                    max( pm.pm_price ) FirstPrice,
                    sum( pm_price( pm.pm_totrank - pm.pm_fromrank +1 )) SumTotalPrice
                from
                    tbl_poolpublish AS pp
                        JOIN tbl_pool AS p 
                            ON pp.pp_poolid = p.p_id
                            AND p.p_status = 'Active'
                        JOIN tbl_poolprizemoney pm
                            ON pp.pp_poolid = pm.pm_poolid
                where
                    NOW() BETWEEN pp.pp_start_time AND pp.pp_end_time 
                group by
                    pp.pp_id,
                    pp.pp_poolid ) Prize
                -- join on same prequeried active pools by publish / poolid
                on AP.Publishid = Prize.publishid
                AND AP.PoolID = Prize.poolid

            -- NOW, only from those pools published and active within the given time period, 
            -- we can join to others such as users participating in a published pool
            JOIN
            ( select
                    pp.pp_id publishid,
                    pp.pp_poolid poolid,
                    usu.user_id,
                    count(*) as StockCount,
                    sum(usu.inves_amount) InvestAmount
                from
                    tbl_poolpublish AS pp
                        JOIN tbl_pool AS p 
                            ON pp.pp_poolid = p.p_id
                            AND p.p_status = 'Active'
                        JOIN tbl_user_stock AS usu 
                            ON pp.pp_id = usu.publish_id
                            AND pp.pp_poolid = usu.pool_id
                            -- since all other tables now joined by respective publish and pool ID,
                            -- dont see a need for the stock price master as per publish/pool and user
                            -- are already resolved an no other columns appear to be used from the table
                where
                    -- and you only cared about a SINGLE USER
                        usu.user_id = 186
                    AND NOW() BETWEEN pp.pp_start_time AND pp.pp_end_time 
                group by
                    pp.pp_id,
                    pp.pp_poolid,
                    usu.user_id ) UserStock
                -- join on same prequeried active pools by publish / poolid
                on AP.Publishid = Prize.publishid
                AND AP.PoolID = Prize.poolid
    where
            AP.PoolCount >= AP.MinimumPoolSize
        -- AND the user met the minimum spend investment amount and count
        AND UserStock.StockCount = 5
        AND UserStock.InvestAmount >= AP.PoolMinimumSpendAmount
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but still your query take 14 seconds to execute the result

Answer (score 0):

Typo in this line?

```
/ ( usedamount )) 100 AS percentchange
```

Suggested indexes:

```
fss:  INDEX(fs_poolid, fs_publishid)
p:  INDEX(p_id,  p_max_user)
p:  INDEX(p_status, p_min_user, p_id)
pl:  INDEX(p_id)
pm:  INDEX(pm_poolid)
pp:  INDEX(pp_start_time, pp_end_time, pp_id,  pp_poolidINNER, 
s:  INDEX(pool_id, pp_id)
s:  INDEX(stock_id, pool_id, pp_id)
us:  INDEX(pool_id)
pp:  INDEX(pp_poolid, pp_id)
usu:  INDEX(user_id, pool_id, publish_id)
us:  INDEX(user_id, stock_id,  pool_id, publish_id)
```

pp_poolid)
usus:  INDEX(user_id, pool_id, publish_id,  inves_amount)

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

If any of these start with the `PRIMARY KEY`, then don't add an `INDEX`.

For DRapp's version, these might help:

```
fs:  INDEX(fs_publishid)
p:  INDEX(p_id,  p_status)
pm:  INDEX(pm_poolid,  pm_price, pm_totrank, pm_fromrank)
pp:  INDEX(pp_start_time, pp_end_time, pp_poolid, pp_id)
UserStock:  INDEX(StockCount, InvestAmount,  User_ID, user_id)
usu:  INDEX(user_id, publish_id,  inves_amount, pool_id)
```

Re `COUNT`:

- `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows -- fastest, easiest to optimize
- `COUNT(fs_userid)` counts the number of rows with `fs_userid IS NOT NULL`, so it may be slower than `COUNT(*)`
- `COUNT(DISTINCT fs_userid)` is likely to give a smaller number.

Which did you want?